# Mix two arrays such that corresponding columns are stacked next to each other - Python

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have two 2D matrix A and B, I want to concatenate each column in A with the respective column in B. For example:

```
A = array([[1, 1],
           [1, 1]])
B = array([[2, 3],
           [2, 3]])
```

So the result I expect is:

```
array([[1, 2, 1, 3],
       [1, 2, 1, 3]])
```

Comment: Should the output be a list? Or a numpy array?

Comment: should be a numpy array, thanks

Comment: And the bottom row is removed (since `a` has three rows)?

Comment: Furthermore what should happen if the difference of columns is more than one between `a` and `b`?

Comment: question lacks proper specification

Comment: Sorry Willem, I have fixed the typo in the question

Comment: @victor: do you want this to work only for a 2d matrix, or can the number of dimensions be arbitrary? In that case, how to handle these dimensions (sorry if you get annoyed, I only want the problem to be specified enough).

Comment: The output looks like you are trying to interleave the rows of A and B, not the columns.  Is that correct?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for your patience. I didn't clarify the problem. Yes, I only want to work for a 2D matrix. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one with [`np.dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) and `reshape` -

```
np.dstack((A,B)).reshape(-1,A.shape[1]*2)
```

Sample run -

```
In [44]: A
Out[44]: 
array([[2, 7, 3, 0, 8],
       [1, 0, 6, 7, 6],
       [3, 4, 7, 7, 6],
       [0, 3, 7, 5, 4]])

In [45]: B
Out[45]: 
array([[8, 4, 3, 8, 0],
       [3, 1, 8, 8, 2],
       [8, 5, 8, 8, 4],
       [1, 0, 6, 1, 7]])

In [46]: np.dstack((A,B)).reshape(-1,A.shape[1]*2)
Out[46]: 
array([[2, 8, 7, 4, 3, 3, 0, 8, 8, 0],
       [1, 3, 0, 1, 6, 8, 7, 8, 6, 2],
       [3, 8, 4, 5, 7, 8, 7, 8, 6, 4],
       [0, 1, 3, 0, 7, 6, 5, 1, 4, 7]])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try concatenate the two arrays, then rearrange the data with `reshape` and `transpose`:

```
x = np.concatenate((A, B)).reshape(2,2,2)
x
# array([[[1, 1],
#         [1, 1]],

#        [[2, 3],
#         [2, 3]]])

x.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(2,4)

# array([[1, 2, 1, 3],
#        [1, 2, 1, 3]])
```

Comment: Thanks! It's helpful

Comment: Please see my answer for something a little more straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

This is achieved most easily through column-major (Fortran) ordering:

```
import numpy as np

def mix_arrays(a,b):
    return np.concatenate((a,b)).reshape(2,4, order='F')
```

With your inputs, `A` and `B`:

```
>>> mix_arrays(A,B)
array([[1, 2, 1, 3],
       [1, 2, 1, 3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply construct a new array with the proper dimensions and use slicing to fill in the numbers correctly. Like:

```
def mix_matrices(a,b):
    (ma,na) = a.shape
    (mb,nb) = b.shape
    if mb < ma:
        ma = mb
    c = np.zeros((ma,na+nb))
    c[:ma,::2] = a[:ma]
    c[:ma,1::2] = b[:ma]
    return c
```

This generates:

```
>>> mix_matrices(A,B)
array([[ 1.,  2.,  1.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  1.,  3.]])
```